# Corrupted data over serial

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, embedded

I have a problem. I have 2 pieces of hardware (similar to pi) and I'm trying to test communication over serial cable between them. Both are linux based but have limited tools. I have wrote a script to send and receive files. When I send a txt file with some text on it, everything works fine. When i try to send a binary file, the data it's not the same, sometimes i get bigger file, sometimes smaller and sometimes just some bytes are changed. I'm wondering for hours why this happens, I set the devices to `raw` mode (for binary file)...

Here's the scrpit I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

    FILE=$2

    send()
    {
            if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
                    echo "File $2 doesn not exist, please introduce a valid file"
            fi
            content=`cat "$FILE"` #Dump the file content into variable
            echo -E  "$content" > /dev/ttyO5 #send the whole content to the other device



    }
    receive()
    {

            if [ -f $FILE ]; then
                    echo "The file already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n
                    read opc
                    if [ "$opc" == "n" ]; then
                            exit 1
                    fi
                    rm "$FILE"
            fi

            while read -t 5 -r -n 1 c; do  # read char by char -r to avoid backslashes to be scaped
                    echo -E -n  "$c" >> $FILE # append char on file -n(to avoid creation of new lines and -E to avoid interpretation of backslashes.

            done < /dev/ttyO5

    }
    case $1 in

            's')
                    send
                    ;;
            'r')
                    receive
                    ;;
            *)
                    echo "Usage $0 [s | r] [FILE]"
                    ;;

    esac
```

To put the devices on `raw` mode, I use `stty -F /dev/ttyO5 raw` and this are the options of the device:

```
speed 9600 baud;stty: /dev/ttyO5
 line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon
-ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0
ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo -echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

My mind tells me that there's a problem when interpretating some chars and that it might be fixed changing some of the options above. I try several, but i cant make it work. If somebody sees something I dont, i would highly appreciate it.

Regards

EDIT: Problem found but not solved. Read and cat dont like the characters `NULL` and `\n`. How could i read those 2 chars?

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to send the data via catting a file. If the file is binary, catting it will lead to garbage output.

Comment: Consider using something like [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM)

Comment: @RamanSailopal I dont think that's the problem. I tried reading byte per byte form the file and i get the same output.I was usgin it like this `while IFS=  read -r -n 1 c;do
             echo -n "$c" >> /dev/ttyO5
            
        done < "$FILE" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `IFS=` before read to allow to read space, tab characters

```
 while IFS= read -t 5 -r -n 1 c; do
```

EDIT: '\n' and '\0' still can't be read.

Compare the two following outputs

```
for i in {{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f}{{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f};do printf '\x'"$i"; done | od -c

for i in {{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f}{{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f};do printf '\x'"$i"; done | { while IFS= read -r -n1 c; do echo -E -n "$c";done;} | od -c
```

EDIT: to read a newline add the option `-d ''`

```
 while IFS= read -t 5 -r -n 1 -d '' c; do
```

If `[[ $c = '' ]]`; so it's the '\0' character in this case, use printf '\0' for example to write it

Following command proves that all character can be copied

```
for i in {{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f}{{0..9},a,b,c,d,e,f};do printf '\x'"$i"; done | { while IFS= read -r -n1 -d '' c; do if [[ $c = '' ]]; then printf '\0'; else echo -E -n "$c";fi;done;} | od -c
```

EDIT:
considering performance `read` is slow, consider using another unix tool : perl

```
perl -e '
    # $/ end of line of input, special variable
    # read one byte at time
    $/=\1;

    my $outfilename=shift;
    open $outfile,">>",$outfilename or die $!;

    while (<>) {
        # do something on output (for example print ascii number)
        print ord($_),"\n";

        # write to out file
        print $outfile "$_";
    }
' "$FILE" < /dev/ttyO5
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved a tiny problem, but the main one is still there. I will upload a picture to make it more clear

Comment: You are probbaly right, on one file there are some 000a that are not on the other one. I put IFS= and some files got correct. Now im trying to add the option -d ' ' but it gives me illegal option -d. I'm not sure my machine supports that option...It's there any other way to see that delim?

Comment: which is the version of bash, are you using the builtin or the command ? `type read`

Comment: It sais `builtin`

Comment: and `bash --version`, OS ?

Comment: `BusyBox v1.20.2 (MUSE) built-in shell (ash)` I'm checking the hexdumps of files and I see 2 characters that are the problem `00` and `0a`

Comment: also concerning performance `read` is very slow maybe consider using another unix tool like perl I will add perl command to answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I said, it has limited tools my HW, and perl is not one of them :(

Comment: there is another solution but not efficient `hexc=$(dd if=/dev/ttyO5 count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null| od -An -tx1 | tr -d ' ')` and `printf '\x'"$hexc"`

Comment: Is it possible to use this one dd to read byte per byte the file? I mean, does it keep the track of what is reading from the file? or if i put it in a while it will read always the first?  and dd still doesnt read the NULL

Comment: yes while input stream is the same file and not close, see the `while ;do;done < file` construct

Comment: don't hesitate to ask in another new question

Comment: Ok, last question hehe I know that construct, but when i use it, I get to read the file, but the while stays running, it doesnt stop.... I explain more, I read the file on while, then i print. On the screen it prints, but when it finishes, it doesnt show the console simbol, it stays stalled, like waiting for something.....

Comment: it's because the exit status of dd is not the exit status of the pipe command maybe try `set -o pipefail`, compare for example `a=$(false|true|true); echo $?`